# Proof equivalence relation

Tags: linear-algebra

It is given the set $A := \left\{ n \in \mathbb{N} : n \le N, \; N \ne 0 \right\}$. For $a,\,b \in A$ we place $a\text{R}b$ if and only if $a,\,N$ have the same least common multiple of $b,\,N$. Prove that $\text{R}$ is an equivalence relation. They describe classes for $N = 10$ and $N = 12$. It reruns the same exercise with the greatest common divisor in place of the least common multiple.

I know that a relationship because both of equivalence, it must have three properties: reflexive, symmetric and transitive. Unfortunately I am in difficulty in applying in this demonstration.You might have to see how? Thanks !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Reflexive: $\text{lcm}(a,N) = \text{lcm}(a,N) \Rightarrow aRa$.
- Symmetric: $aRb \Rightarrow \text{lcm}(a,N) = \text{lcm}(b,N) \Rightarrow \text{lcm}(b,N) = \text{lcm}(a,N)\Rightarrow bRa$.
- Transitive: $\begin{cases}aRb & \\ bRc &\end{cases} \Rightarrow \begin{cases}\text{lcm}(a,N) = \text{lcm}(b,N)& \\ \text{lcm}(b,N) = \text{lcm}(c,N) & \end{cases} \Rightarrow \text{lcm}(a,N) = \text{lcm}(c,N) \Rightarrow aRc$.

Same for $\gcd$ instead of $\text{lcd}$.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

(1) $\text{lcm}(a,N)=\text{lcm}(a,N)$.

(2) If $\text{lcm}(a,N)=\text{lcm}(b,N)$, then...

(3) If $\text{lcm}(a,N)=\text{lcm}(b,N)$ and $\text{lcm}(b,N)=\text{lcm}(c,N)$, then...